# How to fetch data from mongodb in meteor js

Tags: meteor

Hello I just create skeleton meteor js application and write the following code in main js file:

```
People = new Meteor.Collection("people");

People.insert({name: 'test'});
console.log(People.find().fetch());
```

I reload the page and record was inserted in mongodb and I see it in mongodb command line but when I try to fetch result from database receive empty array ?

Answer (score 1):

Collection methods are **asynchronous**: this basically means that they do *not* stop the process until they are finished. Therefore, in your case, you are trying to fetch the previously inserted person without waiting for said insertion to be over.

This is why [Collection.insert](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/insert) can take an optional *callback* function as a parameter, which will be called as soon as the insert is finished:

```
People = new Meteor.Collection("people");

People.insert({name: 'test'}, function () {
  // this will be printed after the insert is done
  console.log(People.find().fetch());
});
// this will be printed after the insert is started, and (probably) before it is finished.
console.log('Insertion started!');
```